# Split a single row in multi rows - SQL Server Management Studio 2018

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I m trying to split a single row into multiple rows without success. Any help or tips will be greatly appreciate.

**Table structure**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far, why didn't they work? There's plenty examples of this type of thing on SO, which examples did you look at and what about them didn't you understand, or didn't work as you expect? Also, please don't post sample data as an image; it's not useful the to volunteers you're asking for help from. Data should be provided as formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements. Thanks.

Comment: @Larnu i totally new in SQL server. Honestly, i search for 'split single row to multi rows', there are many of examples but i dont have the basic knowledge to apply the solutions.

Comment: As you are new to SQL Server (and databases in general it appears), let me give you some advice:  Start with the basics.  Look at "Normalisation" (first normal form etc.) this will help you in the long run.  That first column contains a date, a home team and an away team, that's three distinct data items in one column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `UNPIVOT`. Just cast columns to most largest type and apply it. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Dat_Cha_hOME_Away] VARCHAR(32)
   ,[Date] DATE
   ,[Half_Time_Score] VARCHAR(8)
   ,[Half Time_Goal Scored] CHAR(1)
   ,[Half Time_Goal Conceded] CHAR(1)
   ,[Half_Time_Both Teams Scored] CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource 
VALUES ('2019_...italy01', '2019-03-24', '0-1', 'N', 'Y', 'N')
      ,('2019_...italy02', '2019-03-24', '2-1', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y')
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT [Dat_Cha_hOME_Away]
          ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Date], 121) AS [Date]
          ,CAST([Half_Time_Score] AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [Half_Time_Score]
          ,CAST([Half Time_Goal Scored] AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [Half Time_Goal Scored]
          ,CAST([Half Time_Goal Conceded] AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [Half Time_Goal Conceded]
          ,CAST([Half_Time_Both Teams Scored] AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [Half_Time_Both Teams Scored]
    FROM @DataSource
) DS
UNPIVOT
(
    [value] FOR [column] IN ([Date], [Half_Time_Score], [Half Time_Goal Scored], [Half Time_Goal Conceded], [Half_Time_Both Teams Scored])
) UNPVT;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on @gotqn answer i manage to create my own one getting the desirable outcome. Really appreciate the people who provide useful guidelines and tips.

```
INSERT INTO Ins_Match_Details
SELECT
       [Dat_Cha_Team] + '_' + Results_Type AS [Dat_Cha_Team_Res Typ]
     , [Date]
     , [Championship]
     , [Dat_Cha_Hom_Vs_Away]
     , [Team]
     , [Site]
     , CAST(Results_Type AS NVARCHAR(20))
     , CAST(Results_Value AS NVARCHAR(10))
from
       (
              SELECT
                     [Dat_Cha_Team]
                   , [Dat_Cha_Hom_Vs_Away]
                   , [Date]
                   , [Championship]
                   , [Team]
                   , [Site]
                   , [Half Time Score]
                   , CAST([Half Time_Goal Scored] AS NVARCHAR(180)) AS [Half Time_Goal Scored]
                   , CAST([Half Time_Goal Conceded] AS NVARCHAR(180)) AS [Half Time_Goal Conceded]
                   , CAST([Half Time_Both Teams Scored] AS NVARCHAR(180)) AS [Half Time_Both Teams Scored]
                   , CAST([Half Time_Over 0.5] AS NVARCHAR(180)) AS [Half Time_Over 0.5]
                   , CAST([Half Time_Over 1.5] AS NVARCHAR(180)) AS [Half Time_Over 1.5]
                   , CAST([Half Time_Result] AS NVARCHAR(180)) AS [Half Time_Result]
                   , [Full Time Score]
                   , CAST([Full Time_Goal Scored] AS NVARCHAR(180)) AS [Full Time_Goal Scored]
                   , CAST([Full Time_Goal Conceded] AS NVARCHAR(180)) AS [Full Time_Goal Conceded]
                   , CAST([Full Time_Both Teams Scored] AS NVARCHAR(180)) AS [Full Time_Both Teams Scored]
                   , CAST([Full Time_Over 0.5] AS NVARCHAR(180)) AS [Full Time_Over 0.5]
                   , CAST([Full Time_Over 1.5] AS NVARCHAR(180)) AS [Full Time_Over 1.5]
                   , CAST([Full Time_Over 2.5] AS NVARCHAR(180)) AS [Full Time_Over 2.5]
                   , CAST([Full Time_Result] AS NVARCHAR(180)) AS [Full Time_Result]
              FROM
                     [Soccer_DatabASe].[dbo].[Imd_Match_Details]
       )
       [Imd_Match_Details] UNPIVOT (Results_Value FOR Results_Type in ([Half Time_Goal Scored]
                                                                     , [Half Time_Goal Conceded]
                                                                     , [Half Time_Both Teams Scored]
                                                                     , [Half Time_Over 0.5]
                                                                     , [Half Time_Over 1.5]
                                                                     , [Half Time_Result]
                                                                     , [Full Time_Goal Scored]
                                                                     , [Full Time_Goal Conceded]
                                                                     , [Full Time_Both Teams Scored]
                                                                     , [Full Time_Over 0.5]
                                                                     , [Full Time_Over 1.5]
                                                                     , [Full Time_Over 2.5]
                                                                     , [Full Time_Result]) ) AS ScoresUnpivot
WHERE
       [Dat_Cha_Team] + '_' + Results_Type NOT IN
       (
              SELECT
                     [Dat_Cha_Tea_Res Typ]
              FROM
                     [Soccer_Database].[dbo].[Ins_Match_Details]
       )
```